# How to export failed records which is imported as CSV file by Feeds module in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-feeds

I am upgrading my drupal website's version from 6 to 7. I have used "node import" module for importing contents in druapl 6.

In drupal 7, I have installed "Feeds" module and enabled the available features.

"node import" - Here I had a option to export the failed records with error messages in each imported files.

"Feeds" - But here I have only "log" option to see the failed records as log information.

I need to give a option to user that exports the failed records for each imported files.

Do the drupal provides any modules/hooks ? or I need to customize the code itself ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Create a view with the failed nodes (using appropriate filters), and use [Views Data Export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module to export as CSV, with the format required.

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support exporting in the following types:
>
> - CSV
> - Microsoft XLS
> - Microsoft DOC
> - Basic TXT
> - XML.

If you are new to this module, there is a very good documentation at : https://drupal.org/node/1820452